# NextJS - How to fix "Properly defines charset - Error!"

Tags: next.js, meta-tags, lighthouse

I have a NextJS app with regular static and dynamically created static pages. Both clearly define the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag as you can see in the screenshot. The regular static pages work fine, but I am not sure why Lighthouse is giving this `Properly defines charset Error!` on the dynamically loaded pages. These pages are using 'fetch' to get blog posts through the WordPress API and then showing them on the page, not sure if that has anything to do with it? Please help!

[image: Properly defines charset Error!]
[image: charSet set]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered this was happening because it was fetching an API with too much data. When we took down the amount of data that was returned, it started reporting positive numbers.